# style-m.css style-m.css and print.css not in pub/static

Tags: magento2, css, cache, frontend

I have seen this question a lot, and always with an answer to deploy content or a missing .htaccess in pub/static or to clear cache, processed files in var,

Did all of this without success.

I created a a custom them, or better copied the folder from another of my MAGENTO DIRECTORY.

Permissions and ownership seems alright, they have to be if on pub/static the Luma and Blank are creating files with no problem, I have also custom Js on my custom theme, all deployed  with no problem.

If I work with Grunt (uninstalled now) all LESS files are there, all but these 3 CSS files in the subject. They should be inherited by the Luma theme by configuration anyway.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling everything and the problem dissappear

Answer (score 0):

Location of **pub/static/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/en_US/css/**

Those files will be available in **app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/web/css/bootstrap/**

Check custom theme  *css* folder to check **bootstrap** folder exists or not.

Comment: Is bootstrap an example? Cause I do not have or need a bootstrap folder, Also as already pointed out, I have taken Theme created by me from another Magento installation, and there all work good

Comment: All less file is generate from bootstrap , source folder.

Comment: Yes but there is no documentation about puttinga bootstrap folder in that location